# BigQuery: the difference between 'bq load' and 'bq mk'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a cloud storage bucket with approx 18 table's worth of externally partitioned hive parquets.

For the majority of the parquet files, a shell for loop builds external table definition files and then calls 'bq mk' and makes a table in a dataset in BQ from those defs. The outstanding tables where this fails can later be brought into BQ with 'bq load'. I want to know what the difference is between these tools in general and what ramifications one has between using one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

External table loads data from outside the BigQuery native storage. Some feature aren't available (partitioning, clustering, long term storage, dry run/cost estimation,...) and it's generally slower.

And because partitioning is not available, you pay a full scan of your external table every time.

---

BQLOAD solves that by loading the data in BigQuery storage and by leveraging the full power of BigQuery.

---

For small, non persistent (history not required), and frequently change file, it can makes sense to create external table.

For performances, long term storage, efficiency, BigQuery native tables are better.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a little more information from the answer above.

BigQuery is a serverless data warehouse that lets you manage and store scalable amount of data. The `bq mk` and `bq load` are part of BQ command-line tools.

Datasets are needed to be created first before loading data into BigQuery.
For you to be able to create a dataset, you will use [bq mk](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk). Since BigQuery is a collection of tables, those tables are grouped into datasets. And to load the data into a BigQuery table, you will use the [bq load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load) command.

Note: You have to create first a bucket in Google Cloud Storage where you will upload your `CSV file`. After that you can finally load your data into BigQuery by using the `bq load`.

Comment: I don't think the above is true. I am running bq mk and it is making tables viewable in my dataset. I did not use bq mk to make the dataset, though it may be possibly used to do so as well